# NoClassDefFound on tomcat in eclipse, but i have added it to classpath

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7

Ive looked at other answers to this question, and ive tried following them. Basically here is the scenario: I have a class which is called via a jsp page. That class has a class which is found in a jar file. When I go to that page, i get a class not found exception, for the class that is in the jar.

Upon deployment if I go to the folder it is deployed in I find the jar file in question, and it has the class inside the jar. Ive also tried adding it to eclipse's deployment assembly to no avail.

Any ideas I could try?

This is a dynamic web project in eclipse on tomcat7. Thanks for your input.

edit: it gets ever freakier. I can call other classes from the same folder in the same jar as the one that is generating the class not found exception.

Edit again: its a noclassdeffound exception, not class not found exception. Apologies.

Comment: Where have you placed the jar?  In which way have you added the jar to the classpath?

Comment: the jar is in web-inf/lib of my project... so I thought it would work alone with that. When that wasnt working i added it to the deployment assembly in eclipse which says it will go to we-inf/lib, that didnt work so i tried adding it to tomcat's lib which doesnt work.

Comment: If this is a Dynamic Web Project, whatever's in WEB-INF/lib will already be deployed.  The question then becomes: does the class it's mentioning *itself* require something that's not deployed?

Answer (score 0):

alright, this was a very specific question and I apologize for asking it haha. The class not found was not actually the one it was saying. It was just throwing that for some reason I never found, but it actually couldnt find another Exception class which it was trying to throw. The reason it was doing that is because I needed a fedlet set up for my application. So yea, this issue was specific to my application.